# Error: object of type 'reversed' has no len()?

Tags: python, typeerror

I have as an input a list that i converted it to a string so i can use for my main program (DNA translation) and for that i need its length to find the 3 different frames. Btw it needs mentioning that the user has put an input (DNA sequence eg. ATGCGTAGT).

The first part where i convert my comp seq is this:

```
comp = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C' }

for i in sequence_list :
    comp_sequence += comp[i]

reversed_comp_seq = ''.join(reversed(comp_sequence))
```

And later on, in my program it is used here:

```
for e in range(0, len(reversed_comp_seq)-len(reversed_comp_seq)%3,3):
    Frame4 += codons1[reversed_comp_seq[e:e + 3]]
    print(Frame4)
```

And then i cannot run it to find the reversed translation because it says this:

```
TypeError: object of type 'reversed' has no len()
```

Could you help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Nowhere in this code are you calling `len` on a `reversed` object. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: How about `len(list(reversed(..)))`?

Comment: @dangom i thought about it but Because i need my sequence as a string: e.g. 5- ATGCGATAGTA -3 and its complementary is: 3-
 TACGCTATCAT - 5  and what i need is the reversed complementary which is : 5- TACTATCGCAT- 3 , I cannot convert it as a list :/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but if all you want to do is translate and reverse a DNA sequence you could do:

```
comp = {'A': 'T', 'T': 'A', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C' }

s = 'GATACA'
s_comp = s.translate(s.maketrans(comp))
s_comp_reversed = s_comp[::-1]
```

or do it all at once:

```
def complement_reversed(seq):
    return seq.translate(s.maketrans(comp))[::-1]
```